# Simple ruby request using httparty with input parameters

Tags: html, ruby, post, screen-scraping, httparty

I am learning ruby and attempting a simple ruby request on command line to scrape a website.  There are 2 input elements with ids = "tb_radius_miles" and "locationSearchTextBox"

I am trying to make a request with these values filled in and then read the result which displays in the textarea with id="tb_output"

All of my efforts result in all these tags having empty values when I read them out.

Here is my ruby script:

```
require "httparty" 
require "nokogiri"
require 'json'


response = HTTParty.post("https://www.freemaptools.com/find-zip-codes-inside-radius.htm",
  { 
    :body => [ { "tb_radius_miles" => "10", "locationSearchTextBox" => "10118" } ].to_json,
    :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'}
  })


# parse html of web page
document = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body)
puts document.at_css("textarea#tb_output")
puts document.at_css("input#tb_radius_miles")
puts document.at_css("input#locationSearchTextBox")
```

and here is my output with empty values in these elements

```
<textarea cols="50" rows="4" id="tb_output" name="tb_output" readonly></textarea>

<input type="text" id="tb_radius_miles" value size="4" maxlength="4" onchange="tb_radius_miles_changed(this.value);">

<input type="text" id="locationSearchTextBox" style="width:300px;" placeholder="Example:10118">
```

I am simply expecting the 3 print outs to display the values i am sending in and the result that should be populated in the tb_output element when I run it manually in my browser.

I have tried different syntax for forming the httparty request like using query instead of body, removing the : and also trying the request without json format.

Thanks for any tips, i have spent an embarrassing amount of time reading, googling, and trying to get this most basic script to work.

I am not using any tools except vscode and the installed ruby 3.2.3
Tips on other tools to use would be appreciated as well.

EDIT****
inspecting the page's network tab shows a php request with
parameters when clicking the search button.  Would it be proper
to send this url in though? Does not seem like the correct way
to go about it.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM1iZ.png)
[headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uj1nn.png)
[payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usky5.png)

Comment: Are you sure the site you're sending it to actually works? Looks pretty low quality to me.

Comment: i am able to input the values manually and get the output i want when i type it in the browser.  Is that what you mean by "works"?

Comment: Well lets put it this way. That site is a questionable collection of scripts using the google maps API with very little documentation. If you want to build something thats even remotely reliable you can do a lot better like using the API directly. HTML scraping is a last resort.

Comment: i see, i am just trying to learn ruby and i had a small project i wanted to do with this site.  Are you saying the code I have looks correct?  So it must be the site?

Comment: The assumption that the visible forms fields are directly related to a specific HTTP POST request is not correct. I suggest taking a look at your browser's developer tools when doing the request in the browser. Because you will notice that the browser actually does two requests via JavaScript when submitting the form. The first requests translate the ZIP code to a geolocation and the second request uses longitude, latitude and the radius in kilometers.

Comment: I added an edit to the post about inspecting the element's network tab

Comment: @forgiveness - I understand that you want to learn but this is really just spending a lot of effort on a pretty bad result. Learn to use actual documented API's instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using HTTParty for web scraping, ensure the website doesn't require javascript execution for displaying content. Your current approach might not work if the site relies on JS to populate data. Instead of directly scraping the output, consider using APIs if available. Check the website's robots.txt for legality. Also, double-check if the form submission correctly sends JSON data; you might need to mimic form encoding instead. If javascript rendering is needed, switching to a tool like Selenium might be more effective for your task.